# How to always pick up 30 dates from date range larger than 30. And choose "middle" dates

Tags: php, arrays, math

EDIT:
Let's forget about the dates. If I have an array of 60 items, it's easy. I pick out every second item of the array. But what about an array of 50 items? I have to round up or down to get an array of 30. Is there an easy solution to this? I want to always include the first and the last item of the array.

ORIGINAL:

I'm not sure how to describe this. But I have an array of items (dates) and I want to always pick out 30 if there are more than thirty items in the array. Starting from the first date to the last date in the array. How do I do the math picking out the 28 in the middle to spread it out evenly?

My starting out is ex. 44 items.

```
$max_points = 30;
$i_div = round(44/$max_points, 2);
$i_div = 1,47.
```

How do I use this number to pick out the dates when the array only use whole numbers?

Comment: Well, months all have between 28 and 31 days in them, so if you remove duplicates your worst case scenario is just to remove 1 of the dates from the list...  Maybe there are additional requirements for the dates you want to keep or remove that you forgot to add to the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemArray = array();
$items = 44;

$max_points = 30;

$mid_range = 0 + $items / 2;

$start_count = $mid_range-15;

for( $i=$start_count; $i < 30; $i++ ) {
    $itemArray[] = $yourArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Only outputs the middle 30 dates. Not including the edges.